# How to re-try MySQL connection if the database is temporarily unavailable

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

```
import MySQLdb
```

`MySQLdb.connect` fails sometimes unable to connect, is there a way to set a timeout and try this repeatedly without writing application specific code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abstract your connection code into a method you can call and have it return the connection. Inside that method try to connect to the database up to 3 or 5 times. Do a time.sleep(.01) between each attempt. That is a 100th of a second. If you can go less, that would be better.